# Rails, Puma, Sidekiq how to calculate total DB connections?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-5, puma

I am getting `ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError` once or twice in a day. could someone help me in calculating how many connections my application is making to my DB? and suggestion to optimise my connections?

Here is my configuration

AWS

```
Database : Mysql   
Version  : 5.7.23   
Provider : AWS RDS (db.m5.large, vCPU: 2, RAM: 8GB)
```

3 servers with bellow configurations

```
# database.yml
  pool: 20

# puma.rb 
  RAILS_MAX_THREADS : 5
  WEB_CONCURRENCY   : 2
```

1 sidekiq server with bellow configuration

```
# sidekiq 
  concurrency:  25
```

I tried to get max number of connection my DB is able to handle

```
# MySQL Max connections ("show global variables like 'max_connections';")
  624
```

Answer (score 5):

The total number of connections to a database equals the number of connections per server times the number of servers.

> Total DB Connections = Connections per server * server count.
>
> Connections per server = AR Database Pool Size * Processes per server (usually set with WEB_CONCURRENCY or SIDEKIQ_COUNT)

So for the web servers you have:

> AR Database Pool Size = 20
>
> Processes per server = 2
>
> Server Count = 3
>
> Total DB Connections(Web Server) = 20 * 2 * 3 = 120

The for the sidekiq server:

> AR Database Pool Size = 20
>
> Processes per server = 1
>
> Server Count = 1
>
> Total DB Connections(Sidekiq Server) = 20 * 1 * 1 = 20

So the total expected DB connections should be `140`, which is way below the limit of the RDS instance.

My guess is that you are getting the `ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError` because your Sidekiq concurrency setting is higher than the AR connection pool value. All of the Sidekiq threads need an ActiveRecord database connection, so setting the AR pool size to a number *smaller* than Sidekiq's concurrency means some Sidekiq threads will become blocked waiting for a free database connection. In your case, at some point in time you might have 25 threads trying to access the database through a database pool that can use at most 20 connections and if a thread can't get a free database connection within 5 seconds, you get a connection timeout error.

In Sidekiq the total DB connections should be

> minimum(Threads That Need a Database Connection, AR Database Pool Size) * Processes per Server (WEB_CONCURRENCY or SIDEKIQ_COUNT) * Server Count.

Additionally the Sidekiq [documentation](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options#concurrency) states that

> Starting in Rails 5, RAILS_MAX_THREADS can be used to configure Rails and Sidekiq concurrency. Note that ActiveRecord has a connection pool which needs to be properly configured in config/database.yml to work well with heavy concurrency. Set pool equal to the number of threads `pool: <%= ENV['RAILS_MAX_THREADS'] || 10 %>`

Most of this answer is based on the *Sidekiq in Practice* email series from [**Nate Berkopec**](https://speedshop.co)

Comment: what does `RAILS_MAX_THREADS : 5` will do?

Comment: `RAILS_MAX_THREADS` defines the amount of threads that run inside a Rails process

Comment: @Aparichithdid you able to resolve this? I'm facing the same issue.