# ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError: could not obtain a database connection within 5.000 seconds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, puma

I'm getting this error sporadically on my Prod server.
`ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError: could not obtain a database connection within 5.000 seconds`

I see there is not high CPU usage for DB, but still this error happened once a day maybe twice.

Puma.rb

```
threads 2, 100
workers 2
```

database.yml

```
  pool: 15
```

Ruby
ruby:2.3

Puma

```
puma (3.11.2)
```

DB size

```
db.m5.large
```

Comment: Do you have some sidekiq or something like that? because it can take quite a few connections

Comment: Yes, I have sidekiq running in another container than the APP container in the same instance.

Comment: It could be a big part of your problem, I recommend reading and calculating how many connections your Sidekiq uses https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58426501/rails-puma-sidekiq-how-to-calculate-total-db-connections

Answer (score 8):

In your current configuration, each puma worker has its own connection pool with 15 available database connections. And each worker is allowed to scale between 2 and 100 threads depending on the server load.

This means when the load goes up or there are more long-running requests then your server will run create more than 15 threads and at that point, your database connection pool will be empty and the new threads have to wait for other threads to return database connections. This might take a while and after 5 seconds of waiting you will observe an `ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError` exception.

To solve this issue you have to make sure that the database connection pool is big enough for all your threads. But at the same time, you have to make sure that the total number of all connections in all pools – in the workers plus in sidekiq and other tools (database management tools or Rails consoles) – is below the maximum number of connections available by your database.

My advice is: First, figure out the maximum number of connections in your database. You might find this information in your database's config or in the docs of your database provider. Then split that number overall workers and tools like Sidekiq. Once you know the max number of connections per worker set the max number of thread to that number.

Example: Imaging your database supports 64 connections. Then you might want to run two servers with 2 workers each, a Sidekiq instance with 4 workers and you want to have a buffer to be able to connect a Rails console or a backup system to the database too.

```
2 servers with 2 workers  48
8 sidekiq workers          8
buffer                     8
```

With those numbers, I would set the connection pool in Rails' database config to `12` and would set the number of threads in the puma config to `2, 12`

Read more about this topic at [Concurrency and Database Connections in Ruby with ActiveRecord](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/concurrency-and-database-connections) in the Heroku devcenter.

Comment: Yea I also think the threads count till 100 is a bit too much.

Comment: For db.m5.large, 8 GiB : 2 vCPUs it should be around 676.  

[ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Limits.html#RDS_Limits.MaxConnections) 

my stats 
3 servers with 2 workers  * 100 threads(max)    600
3 servers with 20 sidekiq workers               60 

600+60 == 660
 I guess it is almost consuming it.